# Unity: the null-coalescing operators not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

## Problem

I cannot use `??` and `??=` operators in Unity.

```
public class Compo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform? _tr;

    void Start()
    {
        _tr ??= transform;
        Debug.Log(_tr);
    }
}
```

I attached this class to an object.

I did not attach any `Transform` to `_tr` property but the object's `transform` should be assigned to `_tr`.

Eventually, I got `null` in the console.

## Attempt

I tried not to use the operators like below.

```
if (_tr == null)
{
    _tr = transform;
}
```

Successfully, `transform` was assigned to `_tr`.

Then, I tried simpler code like below.

```
int? x = null;
x ??= 10;
```

I got `10`.

## Environment

- OS: macOS 13.3.1 (a)（22E772610a）
- Unity: 2021.3.22f1
- Mono: 6.12.0.182
- C#: .NET Standard 2.1

Additional Compiler Arguments

- `-nullable:enable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The null-coalescing and null-conditional (`?. and ?[]`) operators compare the reference of the left operand to null.

```
_tr ??= transform;
```

is equivalent to

```
if(object.ReferenceEquals(_tr, null))
    _tr = transform;
```

But all the Unity objects override the `==` operator so that even the references are not null, the objects can be equal to null. For example:

```
var r = GetComponent<Renderer>(); // suppose there is a renderer component attached
DestroyImmediate(r);
print(r == null); // true
print(object.ReferenceEquals(r, null)); // false
```

That's why you should avoid to use these on Unity objects.

Comment: Thank you! I understood why the code is valid.